# Java - Como comparar un ArrayList para que me muestre las lineas con valores boolean?

Tags: java, poo, arraylist

estoy empezando con los arrayList esto bastante verde, ya que he empezado hace unos días, tengo que realizar un menú sobre campañas publicitarias, en la opción 1 quería que me enseñara solo las campañas que tienen un true como dato, enseñando toda la linea, por ejemplo: (1,"Marca","banner","200x200",true)
Al tener true te enseña la linea, si tiene un false la linea con datos no se imprime.
como haría esto?

**Main**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);

    //arrayList
    ArrayList <Empresas> empresa = new ArrayList<Empresas>();
    ArrayList <Campanya> campanya = new ArrayList<Campanya>();
    ArrayList <Campanya> campanyaDet = new ArrayList<Campanya>();

    empresa.add(new Empresas("Las provincias"));
    empresa.add(new Empresas("Marca","Madrid","Espanya"));
    empresa.add(new Empresas("Marca.com"));
    empresa.add(new Empresas("As","Madrid","Espanya"));

    campanya.add(new Campanya(1,"Las provincias","banner","200x200",true));
    campanya.add(new Campanya(2,"Viajar.com","banner","300x600",false));
    campanya.add(new Campanya(3,"viaje a Tokyo","banner","200x200",true));

    campanyaDet.add(new Campanya(1,"Marca",empresa, 25500, 30000));
    campanyaDet.add(new Campanya(2,"Viajar.com",empresa, 20000, 15000));
    campanyaDet.add(new Campanya(3,"viaje a Tokyo",empresa, 15000, 10000));


    System.out.println("Hola! Bienvenido al backoffice de adWords.\n");
    System.out.println("Que deseas hacer:");    
    System.out.println("1) Ver Campanyas activas");
    System.out.println("2) Ver todas las campanyas");
    System.out.println("3) Ver detalles de campanya");
    System.out.println("4) Ver datos empresa relacionada");
    System.out.println("5) Volver atras");

    int menu = lector.nextInt();

    switch(menu){
        case 1:
        for(Campanya c: campanya) { 
                if (c.isEstado().equals(true)) {
                    c.mostrarCampanya();
                }
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            for(Campanya c: campanya) { 
                c.mostrarCampanya();
            }
            break;
        case 3:
            for(Campanya c: campanyaDet) {  
                c.mostrarDetalles();
            }
            break;
        case 4:
            for(Empresas c: empresa) {  
                c.detallesRel();
            }
            break;
        case 5:
            break;
        default:

    }

}

}
```

**objeto Campaña**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Campanya {
private int id;
private String nombre;
private String tipo;
private String formato;
private boolean estado;
private int totalClicks;
private int totalIngresos;
private int enterpriseId;
private ArrayList<Empresas> empresa;

//Constructor ver campaÃ±as
public Campanya(int id, String nombre, String tipo, String formato, boolean estado) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.tipo = tipo;
    this.formato = formato;
    this.estado = estado;
}

//constructor ver detalles de la campaÃ±a
public Campanya(int id, String nombre, ArrayList<Empresas> empresa, int totalClicks, int totalIngresos) {
    this.id = id;
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.empresa = empresa;
    this.totalClicks = totalClicks;
    this.totalIngresos = totalIngresos;
}

//getters y setters
public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public String getTipo() {
    return tipo;
}

public void setTipo(String tipo) {
    this.tipo = tipo;
}

public String getFormato() {
    return formato;
}

public void setFormato(String formato) {
    this.formato = formato;
}

public boolean isEstado() {
    return estado;
}

public void setEstado(boolean estado) {
    this.estado = estado;
}

public void estados(boolean estado) {
    if (this.estado == true) {
        System.out.println("activo");
    }
    if (this.estado == false){
        System.out.println("desactivado");
    }
}


public void mostrarCampanya() {
    System.out.print("id=" + id + ", nombre=" + nombre + ", tipo=" + tipo + ", formato=" + formato+", estado=");
    estados(estado);
}

public void mostrarDetalles() {
    System.out.println("Id: "+id+"\nNombre :"+nombre+"\nEmpresa :"+ this.empresa+"\nTotal Clicks :"+totalClicks+"\nTotal ingresos :"+totalIngresos);
}
}
```

**objeto empresas**

```
public class Empresas {
    private int id;
    private String empresa;
    private String localidad;
    private String pais;

    //constructor empresa relacionada
    public Empresas(String empresa, String localidad, String pais) {
        super();
        this.empresa = empresa;
        this.localidad = localidad;
        this.pais = pais;
    }

    //constructor empresa
    public Empresas(String empresa) {
        super();
        this.empresa = empresa;
    }

    //constructor
    public Empresas(int id, String empresa, String localidad, String pais) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.empresa = empresa;
        this.localidad = localidad;
        this.pais = pais;
    }

    //getters y setters
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getEmpresa() {
        return empresa;
    }

    public void setEmpresa(String empresa) {
        this.empresa = empresa;
    }

    public String getLocalidad() {
        return localidad;
    }

    public void setLocalidad(String localidad) {
        this.localidad = localidad;
    }

    public String getPais() {
        return pais;
    }

    public void setPais(String pais) {
        this.pais = pais;
    }

    public void detallesRel() {
        System.out.println("empresa: " + this.empresa + "\nlocalidad: " + localidad + "\npais: " + pais);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los metodos `mostrarCampanya()`, `mostrarDetalles()` y `detallesRel()` ya imprimen por consola, por lo que en el main solo tienes que poner algo asi:

```
c.mostrarCampanya();
```

Si quieres hacer el `System.out.println()` en el main deberias modificar los metodos para que devuelvan un `String`, ejemplo:

```
public String detallesRel() {
    return "empresa: " + this.empresa + "\nlocalidad: " + localidad + "\npais: " + pais);
}
```

EDIT:

Perdona no me acordaba de la segunda parte, debes meter el `if` dentro del bucle

```
for (Campanya c : campanya) {
    if (c.getEstado() == true) {
        c.mostrarCampanya();
    }
}
```

Comment: Millones de gracias por tu respuesta! la votaría como resulta pero falta la otra parte de la pregunta, aún así me ha servido 100% jaja estoy ya tan mareada que no he caído en ese detalle infinitas gracias!

Comment: El if puedes simplificarlo a `if (c.isEstado()) { ...}`

Comment: Wau has dado en el blanco eso era!!! y justo era hacer una comparacion normal no poner nada de equals, que mareo esto de los arrayList jolines muchisimas gracias!!!!!!!!

Comment: El `equals()` te serviria si creas un objeto `Boolean` si usas el tipo primitivo `boolean` no.

Answer (score 0):

Esta construcción es incorrecta:
Dentro del `if` `c` no está definido. El momento en que se define `c` es en el `for` con `Campanya c`.

```
case 1:
    if (c -> c.getEstado().equals(true)) {
        for(Campanya c: campanya) { 
            c.mostrarCampanya();
        }
    }
    break;
```

Sería más bien así:

```
case 1:
    for(Campanya c: campanya) {
        if (c.getEstado()) { // si getEstado() es true ejecuta c.mostrarCampanya.
            c.mostrarCampanya();
        }
    }
    break;
```

**Nota:** las colecciones como `ArrayList` agrupan conjuntos de objetos, por lo tanto es mejor definir sus nombres con plural. En este caso en lugar de `campanya`, un mejor nombre sería `campanyas`

Comment: vale, entiendo! entonces va dentro porque si no, no lo puede detectar, y una pregunta si le quiero poner el metodo para comparar el estado de true y false que en este caso si no me equivoco es isEstado(); como sería ? porque lo estoy colocando y me sale subrayado en rojo me dice un mensaje que pone "Cannot  invoke equals (boolean) on the primitive type boolean" Modifico mi codigo para que veas como se ve.

Comment: "c.isEstado().equals(true)" `c.isEstado()` devueve una primitiva `boolean`, no un objecto `Boolean`. Los métodos son de los objetos. Podrias hacer `if( new Boolean(c.isEstado()).equals(true))` o `if(c.isEstado() == true)` y funcionaría, pero igualmente es una redundancia. Es como decir "Si verdadero es igual a verdadero".

Comment: vaya! comprendo jeje infinitas! gracias!!! :)